# htaccess not replacing underscore in complete url

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to replace all the underscores with dashes in my website. There are some problems that im facing.

**issue 1**

below is a url in my site

```
http://localhost/uk_london when clicked redirects to http://localhost/uk-london
```

but the below url adds an additional dash at the end of the url and returns a 404 error

```
http://localhost/united_states http://localhost/united-states- (gives 404)
```

when i remove the dash at the end it works properly.

**issue 2**

the dash is replaced only when there is only one segment in the url. in the below url none of the underscores are replaced with dashes.

```
http://localhost/london_uk/city/products_availability_london
```

below is my code in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^assets - [L,NC]

RewriteRule !\.(html|php)$ - [S=4]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=uscor:Yes]

RewriteCond %{ENV:uscor} ^Yes$
```

im new to htaccess and want to know what causes these issues. 
Any help to solve the problems will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=uscor:Yes]
```

With just:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,E=uscor:Yes]
```

The rewrite engine will loop and remove all of the underscores, as long as you don't have more underscores than th internal redirect limit (will result in 500 error).

Comment: @Joni-Lin When i replace that code none of the underscores are replaced? it just works as the usual site... any ideas why?